# Fluent NHibernate Composite Key Query

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

I am a newbie to Fluent Nhibernate and .NET. So please let me know if my question is not clear.

I have 3 tables in app as below

### Table A

AID(PK), CreatedDate(PK), ZID, AFirstname, ALastname, AAddress, AZipCode

### Table B

CID(PK), AID(PK), Date(PK), Field1, Field2

### Table C

CID (PK), Cname

Please correct me if I am wrong. My Model Classes look like below.

```
public class A {
    public A() {}
    public virtual long AID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ZID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string AFirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ALastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AZip { get; set; }
    public virtual string AAddress { get; set; }
}
```

MapperClass for Class A

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A> {
    public AMap() {
        Table("A");
        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.AID, "AID").KeyProperty(x => x.CreatedDate, "CreatedDate");
        Map(x => x.ZID).Column("ZID").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.AFirstName).Column("AFirstname").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ALastName).Column("ALastname").Not.Nullable();
        //Same as above for Address and ZipCode
      }
}
```

My B Model Class looks like below

```
public class B{
public B() { }
public virtual long AID { get; set; }
public virtual int CID { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
public virtual string Field1 {get; set; }
public virtual string Field2 {get; set; }
}
```

Mapper Class for Class B

```
public class BMap : ClassMap<B> {
    public BMap() {
        Table("B");
        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.AID, "AID").KeyProperty(x => x.CID, "CID").KeyProperty(x => x.Date, "Date");
        Map(x => x.Field1).Column("Field1").Not.Nullable();
        //Same for Field2
    }
}
```

My Table C Model Class looks like below.

```
public class C{
        public C() { }
        public virtual int C{ get; set; }
        public virtual string Cname{ get; set; }
}
```

MapperClass for Class C

```
public class C: ClassMap<C> {
    public C() {
        Table("C");
        Id(x => x.CID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("CID");
        Map(x => x.CName).Column("Cname").Length(64);
    }
}
```

Now many might argue that the table designs are not proper. But nothing can be done at this point and definitely this kind of design may degrade the performance but I guess we have to live with this for a little while.

Now I want some help in writing the mapping for all the three tables. Also can i use Criteria API to write a query for this to join all the 3 tables.

In my Application I get the ZID from another function. Now depending on the ZID i need to grab AFirstName, ALastName, Field1,Field2, CName. How can this be possible?

Please help. Also let me know if the problem is not clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where is your mapper classes?

Comment: If you are a beginner, i would recommend you to pick the easiest possible solution, you can solve this with.

Comment: Just added the Mappers classes. Please let me know if that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply DarthVader. This sample which i m trying to do is already half done and i cannot start with something new now. And yes i know the basics of C# and Fluent NHibernate a little. I just want few ideas to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

replace the ids with references to the original properties so you can navigate them

```
public class B
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
    public virtual string Field1 {get; set; }
    public virtual string Field2 {get; set; }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Table("B");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.A, "AID", "Date")
            .KeyReference(x => x.C, "CID");

        Map(x => x.Field1, "Field1").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Field2, "Field2").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

// query for it

var results = session.CreateCritera<B>()
    .JoinAlias("A", "a")
    .JoinAlias("C", "c")
    .SetProjection(Projections.List()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Field1"), "Field1")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Field2"), "Field2")
        .Add(Projections.Property("a.CreatedDate"), "Date")
        .Add(Projections.Property("c.Name"), "CName"))
    .SetResulttransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<YourDto>())
    .List<YourDto>();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Firo that was really helpful. Sorry for the delayed response.